# QStringList "index out of range"

Tags: qt, outofrangeexception, qstringlist

I am trying to reverse the words within a `QStringList`.  Below is the code up to now, but I keep on getting a "Index out of Range" error.  From the error it would seem that I am trying to use data that is out of scope, but not able to figure out my problem.

```
QString reversed;
QStringList reversedlist;
QStringlist list = input.split(" ");

for (int i=0;i<list.length(); ++1)
  reversedlist[i] = list[list.length() -1 -i];

reversed = reversedlist.join(" ");`
```

Thanks

Comment: 'QString reversed;
QStringList reversedlist;
QStringlist list = input.split(" ");

for (int i=0;i<list.length(); ++1)
  reversedlist[i] = list[list.length() -1 -i];

reversed = reversedlist.join(" ");'

Comment: try changing your for loop like this: for (int i=0;i<list.length(); ++i){
  reversedlist[i] = list[list.length() -1 -i];}

Comment: What does it do? `++1`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @ThorngardSO, the `reversedlist` is initially empty, and you are trying to access the invalid index in your loop code. You should add values to the list using one of the following functions:

- STL-*compatible* function [`push_back()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_back) (inserts value at the **end** of the list)
- STL-*compatible* function [`push_front()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_front) (inserts value at the **beginning** of the list)
- Qt function [`append()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append) (Qt alternative for `push_back`)
- Qt function [`prepend()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#prepend) (Qt alternative for `push_front`)

As you see, `prepend()` inserts the element at the **beginning** of the list, that is why it makes the reversing of the list very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    reversedlist.prepend(list[i]);
}
```

Also, note that there is a **typo** in your loop: it should be `++i` instead of `++1`.

Comment: `prepend` and `push_front` need to move all the other elements forward in the array at each insertion (which is O(n)); you just made O(n^2) an operation which would be O(n) if done correctly.

Comment: @MatteoItalia from [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#prepend): *QList preallocates extra space on both sides of its internal buffer to allow for fast growth at both ends of the list*

Comment: Uh jeez, for some reason I was thinking QVector. Do some edit to your post (for example, add this quotation to underline that this differs from QVector and/or std::vector), so that I can reverse my vote.

Comment: @MatteoItalia added "STL-*compatible*" remark to prevent misunderstandings. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @ThorngarSO - worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: @mvanstad You are commenting not the ThorngardSO's answer :) Don't forget to mark his answer as accepted, if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your reversedList is initially empty. You have to actually append the items, like this:

```
reversedlist.push_back (list[list.length () - 1 - i]);
```

Naturally, trying to access non-existing items via `reversedList[i]` does not work and throws the index-out-out-range error.

Answer (score 0):

You got the index out of range as there is no sting inside the QStringList reversedlist. So when your code reach the line reversedlist[0], it throw the "index out of range" error. And you can read the value using [0] and cant assign.
if you want to assign the value to a particular index of the QStringList.

```
QString reversed;
    QStringList reversedlist;

    QString input="123 456 789 000";
    QStringList list = input.split(" ");

    for (int i=0;i<list.length(); ++i){
      //value to particular index
      reversedlist.insert(i,list[list.length() -1 -i]);
    }

    reversed = reversedlist.join(" ");

    qDebug() << reversed;
```